# How do I change template engine in Play Framework?

Tags: java, playframework, template-engine

How would I change the template engine in Play! to a different engine than the default one? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't even ask why you want to do that.

That's simple, Play can return `Result` with ANY content you will give it, so you can just easily use:

```
return ok("<h1>Code rendered from your alternative engine</h1>").as("text/html");
```

Comment: As per motivation, other template engines may just be more favorable.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on which template engine you want to use.  There are a number of options in [Play's Module Directory](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Modules).

Comment: Nothing really fancily maintained there in terms of good template engine integrations...