# Play 2.5 - Storing Templates in a Database

Tags: java, html, templates, playframework

I'm using Play 2.5 and there is a requirement to store all of the relevant static HTML Template data in a column in the database that we can then call and pass relevant object into.

This is proving difficult as it seems that Play requires the template to exist as static files included in the classpath prior to running.

For example, say I have an **index.scala.html** file that looks like this:

```
<html>
Hello @name!
</html>
```

I want to store this template in a variable (i.e. *String template*) that I can pass objects into like so:

```
String template = GreetingDTO.getTemplate();

Content html = template.render(User.getName());
```

This is essentially all I do to do regarding templating at this point. I need to format some passed in objects into a user-editable HTML layout for E-mail Notifications.

Is this possible without hacking around with Play's classpath structure? Where would I even begin with this? Could I possible achieve this easier by using a different template engine than Twirl. The only example I have found is [this](https://github.com/guillaumebort/play2-freemarker-demo) old Freemarker post from several years ago so was hoping there might be something a little more current.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use Twirl, the default template engine, because it is compiled to scala code and then to bytecodes and that all happens at compile/build time. From [the docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplates#Overview):

> Templates are compiled as standard Scala functions, following a simple naming convention. If you create a `views/Application/index.scala.html` template file, it will generate a `views.html.Application.index` class that has an `apply()` method.

Of course, it is possible to [change the template engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947850/how-do-i-change-template-engine-in-play-framework) and you can use another template engine that better fits your requirements (dynamically load and parse templates). Finally, take a look at the [modules directory](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ModuleDirectory#Templates-and-View).